# Nodejs : multiple projects workflow

Tags: node.js

Suppose you have this setup :

`root
      project1
        package.json { "version" : "0.0.1" }
      project2
        package.json  { "version" : "0.0.1", 
                        "dependencies" :  { "project1" : "^0.0.1"] }
      main
        package.json ("dependencies" : {  "project1" : "^0.0.1" }`

Project1, project2, projectXxxx... and main have to change together. They potentially *all* change *all the time* (it's hardly possible to implement anything in main without dependencing on project1, project2, etc... This is *not* the scenario of a rarely changed library.)

How do you avoid those two pitfalls :

- You can use 'npm link' locally. But then, every developper has to *manually* call 'npm link' in all projects, in the right order. 
  The workflow of a new developper (or someone who just checked out a new dev branch) being :

  - cd main
  - npm install
  - get an error because project2 is missing
  - npm link ../project2
  - get an error because project1 is missing
  - cd ../project2
  - npm link ../project1
  - npm install
  - cd main
  - npm install

Make it more than two projects, and it's madness.

- Or you can use a "preinstall" script to do the 'npm link' for you (as suggested in many other SO questions), but actually, you can't, because the docs tells you *not* to use preinstall script  : https://www.npmjs.org/doc/scripts.html

> tl;dr Don't use install. Use a .gyp file for compilation, and
>   prepublish for anything else.
>
> You should almost never have to explicitly set a preinstall or install
>   script. If you are doing this, please consider if there is another
>   option.
>
> The only valid use of install or preinstall scripts is for compilation
>   which must be done on the target architecture.

- Or you can publish each modules to a private repository, every time you change something. The workflow being (as far as I understand) :

  - edit a file in project1
  - bump version
  - npm publish project1
  - go back to project2
  - npm install
  - edit
  - npm publish project1
  - go back to main
  - npm install
  - edit
  - realize you've done a mistake and start again. Madness, too.

As you can see, none of this is acceptable.

So what would you change to get a reasonnable workflow ?

Do you put everything in the same project ? (Sadly, it is not acceptable in my case since some other project somewhere else will need project1, too.)

Am I missing an 'npm xxxxx' command that does this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what would normally be minor nuisances are becoming major problems for you because your project design has not achieved loose enough coupling. Fundamentally I think you have a code smell that in some form or another main, project1, and project2 are really still a monolithic application and should be a single module, or that project1 isn't abstracted properly so it can be split off and used by main2. Keep refactoring it and at some point you'll have a lightbulb moment and find a cleaner organization.

However, in the mean time, I do have a suggestion for you that should help. When I was in a similar situation, we kept all the helper modules as separate projects in their own private github repos and when a new developer cloned main we had a shell script to set of the following structure, the key to which is the `node_modules` being one directory higher than normal:

```
ROOT
  main
  project1
  project2
  node_modules
    project1 (symlink to ../project1)
    project2 {symlink to ../project2)
```

This allows for two development modes:

- `cd main && npm install` will put you in normal mode and will install the sibling projects in `ROOT/main/node_modules/project1` as normal

  - use this when mostly working on main
  - also use this when doing final testing before committing updates to `main/package.json`
- `cd main && rm -rf node_modules/project[12]` will put you in simultaneous development mode

  - when code in `main` does `require("project1")` it will find it from the local `ROOT/node_modules/project1` symlink and you can rapidly edit code in any of the projects. No need to bump version numbers, push commits, or npm install anything to test changes.
  - When done, `cd main && npm install` gets you back into normal mode

Due to the use of symlinks, this may not work well on Windows, FYI.

You can write a shell script in `main` that your developers can run to set up this structure when they first clone the `main` repo.

Comment: I take the "refactor" advice, but I'm afraid if I split it more, I I'll run into even more of this "projectX depends on projectY" issues. It's not even becoming messy yet : I only have *one* project (project2) that I need to share between main1 and main2. I have already split it to separate concerns, hence the dependency on project1 -  and I already can't figure things !  And for a large part, project2 is really just there to gather files that must be served by main1 and main2. There isn't even a bit of logic ; it's just acting like a shared folder - that is just edited all the time...

Comment: As for your script, how does node know that the "node_modules" folder *next* to main contains dependencies of "main" ? Is that standard ? Thanks anyway !

Comment: Yes, that is the standard search algorithm that node's `require` function uses. It looks up and up in the filesystem all the way to the root if necessary.

Comment: Also, can we at least agree that "use a shell script" is a sign that npm is seriously failing here ? Or is this setup so uncommon ?

Comment: Your situation is not that common. I've only had this in one project in my many node apps. I don't consider this a "serious" failure on npm's part. Could it be better? Probably. Are there more pressing issues with npm? Definitely.

Comment: So what exactly is uncommon : that "main1" and "main2" depends on a shared lib "project" ? That the lib changes too often ? That the lib itself depends on another lib ? How would I mitigate that ? How could spliting the lib projects help (I already *don't* want to have to publish a lib, how would having to publish several of them help ?) I'm obviously missing something here, it's getting frustrating, sorry for the ranting tone...

Comment: `require`'s search algorithm : https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together

Comment: I strongly disagree with you @PeterLyons. Codevelopment of a library and it's dependent is a fundamentally sound (and I would argue, the best) way to develop a library. Codevelopment means that the both components are meant to and do change together all the time. The lack of a sane workflow for this in npm is a real limitation of npm.

Comment: It is absolutely an essential requirement of any other programming solution to be able to co-develop code that needs to be re-used for different purposes, like the most simple: a server, a client, and a common lib. It is extremely cumbersome to handle the current workflow even as a solo developer on a project.